Prove or give a counter-example to switching the integration and summation

Given that $0<|x|\le1\implies \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_kx^k=f(x)$, $\alpha>0,a_k$ is an arbitrary sequence, show or give a counter-example that:
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k\frac{\sin(kx)}{x^2+\alpha^2}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{x^2+\alpha^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Given that the LHS and RHS converge.

My attempt:
Take $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_k\sin(kx),\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$
Take $$g=g(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|a_k|\ge \sum_{k=-n}^{n}|a_k\sin(kx)|\ge|f_n(x)|$$
Hence $$\int_0^\infty\frac{g}{x^2+\alpha^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{g\pi}{2\alpha}<\infty$$
But I realized that the question didn’t say $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|a_k|$ converge, so this technique doesn’t work.
I have also tried to think of a counter-example, but I couldn’t find any.
Does anyone know how to prove or give a counter-example to it? Any hints would be appreciated!

In that case, what exactly does $0<|x|\le1\implies \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_kx^k=f(x)$ mean? I would have interpreted it as $f(x)\inℝ$ for $x\in [-1,1]\setminus{0}$

@ConnFus Which means $f(x)$ has such a series expansion which converge for $|x|\le1$, $\ln|x|$ don’t have that kind of expansion.

Another question: Since the LHS converges, we have that its integrand is integrable. In that case, shouldn't it follow from the properties of the Lebesgue integral that we can swap sum and integral?

@ConnFus Can we? Don’t we need monotonic or other conditions?

The following is a proof that you can always swap integral and sum in $\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_n d\mu$, as long as $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_n$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$.

Define $F_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n f_n$ and $F:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_n$. Let $F$ be integrable.
Since $F$ is integrable, we can split it into positive and negative parts:
$$
\int_{\Omega}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_nd\mu=\int_{\Omega} F d\mu=\int_{\Omega}{F^{\left(\geq0\right)}+F^{\left(<0\right)}}d\mu=\int_{\Omega} F^{\left(\geq0\right)}d\mu+\int_{\Omega} F^{\left(<0\right)}d\mu
$$
Here then $\int_\Omega F^{(\ge0)}d\mu =\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^\infty f^{(\ge0)}d\mu = \int_\Omega F_n^{(\ge0)}$, and since the sequence $(F_n^{(\ge0)})_{n\inℕ}$ is monotone, we get by monotone convergence that $\int_\Omega F^{(\ge0)}d\mu =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\Omega f^{(\ge0)}d\mu  $. Similar for $F^{(<0)}$.
Therefore we can carry on with the equality chain:
$$
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(\geq0\right)}d\mu}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(<0\right)}d\mu}\\=\lim_{N\to\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(\geq0\right)}d\mu}}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(<0\right)}d\mu}\\=\lim_{N\to\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(\geq0\right)}d\mu}+\int_{\Omega}{f_n}^{\left(<0\right)}d\mu}\\=\lim_{N\to\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\Omega}{{f_n}^{\left(\geq0\right)}+{f_n}^{\left(<0\right)}}d\mu}}\\=\lim_{N\to\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\Omega} f_nd\mu}}
$$

Does that mean $\sum\int f$ conv. $\implies \sum\int f = \int\sum f$?

No, that direction doesn't hold. Think about $f_1=f_2=...$ as some function that integrates to $0$, but is both postive and negative on a set of measure >0 each. Then $\sum\int f_n$ is just a sum of zeroes, but $\int\sum f_n$ has unbounded positive and negative parts, so isn't integrable

I mistyped, I should be asking whether $\int\sum f$ conv. $\implies\sum\int f=\int\sum f$. I felt like you were proving an extremely convenient result.

If I didn't make any mistake in my proof it should indeed mean that. If you can find a counter-example, then my proof has to be flawed
